# Bottom tab host background size not reducing

Tags: android, background, size, android-tabhost

I downloaded bottom tab host provider and merge it in my application. Now the only problem is that the size of bottom tab host background is not reducing even if i change the height.
Here is my Tabhost provider code:

```
public class MyTabHostProvider extends TabHostProvider 
{
private Tab homeTab;
private Tab contactTab;
private Tab shareTab;
private TabView tabView;
private GradientDrawable gradientDrawable, transGradientDrawable;

public MyTabHostProvider(Activity context) {
    super(context);
}

@Override
public TabView getTabHost(String category) 
{
    tabView = new TabView(context);
    tabView.setOrientation(TabView.Orientation.BOTTOM);
    tabView.setBackgroundID(R.drawable.tab_background_gradient);
```

As you see the last line, there is a drawable xml file named as tab_background_gradient

tab_background_gradient code is here:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:shape="rectangle"
>
<gradient
    android:angle="270"
    android:endColor="#585858"
    android:startColor="#585858"
    />
<size
    android:height="50dp"
    android:width="540dp"/>
```

See the height is 50dp and in the Screenshot you see the results but i want to reduce its height. Even if i change it to 30dp then the preview of that xml file shows reduced tab background but when run in the real device then nothing changes.
Help Please[image]

Comment: @ArslanAli why didt you hire some developer for your answers ! we are helping here not getting orders.

Comment: @ArslanAli `I need answer for what i asked` is not good choice of words otherwise best of luck for your question.